# How do I use IF/ELSE or CASE In DataColumn.Expression?

Tags: c#, sql, expression, datacolumn

I have a table with 1 column: 'Status' 
I want to add in another column named 'Action', its value will be as follow: if Status = 'Yes' Then Action = 'Go', otherwise, Action = 'Stop'. I used this following code to add in column 'Action' but it didn't work:

```
myDataTable.Columns.Add("Action", typeof(string), "IF [Status] = 'Yes' THEN 'Go' ELSE 'Stop' END");
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The expression you are looking for is:

```
IIF( [Status] = 'Yes', 'Go', 'Stop' )
```

DataTables do not support standard SQL `CASE` statements, nor do they support "IF... ELSE" statements. You must use the inline-if function: `IIF`

See [DataColumn.Expression Property (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know since when but now it's supported, u can use IIF function as a column expression ([check it here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-6.0#functions))

Example: `myDataColumn.Expression = "**IIF(total>1000, 'expensive', 'dear')**"`