# Data Column Expression IIF

Tags: c#, ado.net

I don't know if its possible to have IIF expression that if its null or '' something like it would set a default value then if it have its own value it will retain

```
dtexample.Columns["tagForSomething"].Expression = "iif(tagForSomething = '',0,tagForSomething )";
```

I tried this things but it causes an error

For last note, as much as possible i don't want to use foreach code for this
imagine having hundreds and thousands in your data table.

So I'm hoping to use the expression in data column

Comment: What DAL/ORM are you using here? Tagging your question with that would be helpful.

Comment: I'm so sorry I'm not familiar with the term you use, may you enlighten me with this?

Comment: [DAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer) and [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)

Comment: Looks like [ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this expression. You said that it "causes an error" -- what error?

Comment: Think you need to suround you fieldnames with  []  iif([tagForSomething] = '',0,[tagForSomething] )

Comment: This is the error message given if i use the argument
System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot set Expression property due to circular reference in the expression.'

Comment: I don't  think there will be any changes if I add [] in the column names - It is an expression after all

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325064/how-do-i-use-if-else-or-case-in-datacolumn-expression) could help

Comment: I've seen that one but what I want is if it detects that the column has value it will retain but if its null or empty it will give a default value.

Comment: I think you should add your Expression to a new column ... not to the column you use inside your Expression ... I don't think a recursive Expression like yours is supported.

Comment: @RichardMarkBonifacio On second glance, the recursive error makes sense. You can't have the projection of the `tagForSomething` column depend on `tagForSomething`, that doesn't make sense.